# How to use Nautilus as FTP: Connect to Server not working

Tags: nautilus, ftp

I am trying to connect to my FTP server from nautilus. I am simply trying to update some .html files. I enter my domain here, but nothing happens and I cannot click "connect". Any suggestions?

[image: Connect to Server]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just below the textbox is the example of what to enter. So your entry should look like these:

```
ftp://mydomain.com
```

Or

```
ftp://www.mydomain.com
```

Also check to see if your ftp server allows connections from your machine as I'm assuming you might have used ftp on another system and it worked quite well. Also do all other normal checks to see if you can ping your server you are trying to reach to make sure your machine isn't having problems altogether just to do some elimination.

**EDIT:**

If you are trying to connect a server on your local network then the same above applies with the hostname of the system or if none is set the IP address should work as well. Example:

```
ftp://127.0.0.1
```

Or

```
ftp://myothermachine
```

Comment: Yes, adding "ftp://" was the key.

Comment: Or ftps: ssh://user@host/

Comment: @WHK your URL is sftp, not ftps